# How to display a form field as hyperlink?

Tags: forms, hyperlink

I'm using form to display values from database, edit it and submit again to the database.

A table inside a form and in it's tr

```
<tr>
 <td><label for="userwebsite">Website</label></td>
 <td>
  <div class="input-field-pair-edit-user">
   <form:input path="userWebsite" id="userWebsite" />
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

What i need is when displayed i want to show the website (the value i get in "userWebsite") url as hyperlink.

Comment: try this .... <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="">Website</a>

Answer (score 0):

for make hyper link to your website...

```
<tr>
 <td><label for="userwebsite"><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" target="">Website</a></label></td>
 <td>
  <div class="input-field-pair-edit-user">
   <form:input path="userWebsite" id="userWebsite" />
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

[Ref Link](http://www.hyperlinkcode.com/make-hyperlink.php)

Comment: what i need to display as hyperlink is the value I get in "userWebsite"

Comment: can you write your code ,yes i think userwebsite link write in anchor tag.

Comment: just place your userwebsite variable in anchor tag hre attribue. like: <a href="<?php echo userwebsite; ?>">$userwebsite </a>

Comment: The website name is displayed by the code  path="userWebsite",where userWebsite is the name of that particular field in model class of the table where user details is saved. so i need a way to edit the path and inclide hyperlink.

Comment: can you write you path="userWebsite" code ? where you are getting website link?

Comment: I've written the code in question. I'm using spring and hibernate and by giving the path as the value in model class of the table, i'm displaying the website as text.

Comment: then use this <a href='userwebsite'>website</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
inside your <td> tag, 
<a href="http://www.yourwebsite.com">This is My Site</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag like My WebSite inside your  then it works fine.

Here is the sample code to open a google from your table

```
<tr>
 <td><label for="userwebsite">Website</label></td>
 <td>
   <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  <div class="input-field-pair-edit-user">
   <form:input path="userWebsite" id="userWebsite" />
  </div>
 </td>
```